# Error 2585 on Close Form: action can't be carried out while processing a form or report event

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

My Access form resets a user password that is stored in the database using a SHA-256 encryption.

I'm given the below error.

> Run Time error '2585':
>   This action can't be carried out while processing a form or report event.

I tried the "DoEvents" function just before "DoCmd.Close" and I receive the same error.

```vb
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()

If (IsNull(Me.txtConfirm) Or IsNull(Me.TxtPassword)) Then
    MsgBox "Either the password or confirmation field are empty! Please try again", , ""
Else
    If (Me.txtConfirm.Value = Me.TxtPassword) Then
        If (Me.txtConfirm = "password" Or Me.TxtPassword = "password") Then
            MsgBox "Cannot use 'password' as a password!" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Please try again", , ""
        Else
            MsgBox "Your password has been reset!", , ""
            Call Reset_Password(DLookup("Username", "getCurrentUser"), _
                                SHA256(Me.txtConfirm, True))
            DoCmd.Close
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogin"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "The passwords you entered do not match!" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Please try again", , ""
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Specify explicit what to close`DoCmd.Close acForm, "formName"`as the actual object can be changed by your code. Show the code of`Reset_Password`. You can try moving the close command to the end of `Reset_Password`, but first remove it and test the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing these commands:

```
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogin"
```

or move the last command to the *Unload* event of the form.

Comment: So I've just tried remove the DoCmd.OpenForm "frmLogin" I've also tried swapping order of the two and I'm still receiving the error on that line... The function I created before runs an SQL script, could this be the issue? Maybe it's not given enough time to finish the SQL script?

Comment: Well, remove the call of the function, and you'll see.